# mongodb aggregate function response with long waiting time

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

MongoDB aggregate function takes to much time i.e minutes to perform an operation within the function.
I need to run this query as fast as much as possible. kindly give your suggestion. I someone gives me a good solution I will be very thankful.

```
exports.finddate = (req, res) => {
     var a=req.query.osm_start_node_id;
     var b= req.query.osm_end_node_id;
     var num=parseInt(a);
     var num1=parseInt(b);
     console.log(a);
     var date1=req.query.utc_timestamp;
   console.log(date1);
speeddata.aggregate([{ $sort: {"properties.osm_start_node_id":1,_id:1} },
{ $match:{'osm_start_node_id': num,'osm_end_node_id':num1,'utc_timestamp':{$gte:date1[0],$lte:date1[1]}}},

    {$group:{_id: {
        day: { $dayOfWeek:{ $dateFromString: {
        dateString: "$utc_timestamp"
    } } }},
    meanspeed:{$avg:{$round:["$speed_mph_mean",0]}}}}

]).allowDiskUse(true)
  .then(stable => {

      if(!stable) {
          return res.status(404).send({
              message: "record not found " + req.query.osm_start_node_id
          });            
      }
      res.send(stable);
      console.log(stable);
  }).catch(err => {
      if(err.kind === 'osm_start_node_id') {
          return res.status(404).send({
              message: "record not found " + req.query.osm_start_node_id
          });                
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
          message: "something wrong with name " + req.query.osm_start_node_id
      });
  });
 };
```

Comment: Remove `{ $sort: {"properties.osm_start_node_id":1,_id:1} }`, it does not contribute

Comment: still very slow almost like same as before.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? You should have this one: `{'osm_start_node_id': 1,'osm_end_node_id':1,'utc_timestamp':1}`

Comment: yes i did the indexing

Comment: You might also add timestamp and mean speed to that index, like `{'osm_start_node_id': 1,'osm_end_node_id':1,'utc_timestamp':1,'utc_timestamp':1,'speed_mph_mean':1}` and immediately after the match, project `{'_id':0,'utc_timestamp':1,'speed_mph_mean':1}`.  This might allow the query to only need to consult the index and not actually load the full documents from the disk.

Comment: same issue is happening.

Comment: i tried same aggregation in compass it also gives same problem at group